# Checking if an element exist in about cuda list

Tags: python, list, dataframe

I have 2 lists (`pandas.core.series.Series`) and I want to list elements that doesn't exist in the other series. So I'm using `not in` operator but it doesn't work and the code prints the whole list instead.

```
for i in list1:
  if i not in list2:
    print(i)
```

This code prints the whole list1 instead of printing elements that don't exist in list2. I know this should be a simple task but I'm stuck, can someone help me?

Answer (score 0):

It may work.

```
for i in list(list1): #if list1, list2 are of <class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
    if i not in list(list2): 
        print(i)
```